# Show and hide DIV only on selected user (Laravel 6.x)

Tags: php, html, laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-6

How to hide or show a div on a specific user with?
For example I have an account with role type=1 in database and another account with role type=2.

I want to show some div that only the account has a role type=1 can see.

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a relationship between users and roles, your user role should be accessed through $user->role.

In that way, you can just do the following

```
@if(\Auth::user()->role->type === 1)
<div> Div to show for user type 1 </div>
@endif
```

You are getting information about the current logged in user by using `\Auth::user()`

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
//...
@if($user->type == 1) 
//your 1st div goes here
@elseif($user->type == 2)
//your 2nd div goes here
@endif
```

Comment: @if($user->id == 1)
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        {{ __('Departments') }}
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-desktop"></i>
                        {{ __('Counters') }}
                    </a>
                </li>
                @endif

I tried this. but not working

Comment: Could you add your db schema , models, views and controller code to your post ?